# How create sub-folders in command handler?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I want to create subfolders to put the .py files in them
Example: Put ban.py in moderation
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxTOK.png)

thats my cogs command:

```
for filename in os.listdir('./commands/.'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'commands.{filename[:-3]}')
```

Answer (score 1):

i made work, for peoples who like to know:

```
for folder in os.listdir(f'./commands/.'):
    for filename in os.listdir(f'./commands/{folder}/.'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            client.load_extension(f'commands.{folder}.{filename[:-3]}')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this for your situation as I'm fairly new to the function, but now there is a new function in the os library called os.walk(). The new function is faster & it also scans the directory you give it as well as all subdirectories within the root of the search for files and adds the root, subdirectories, and all files found to their own lists.

Comment: At least consider adding an example.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).